# Cambiar numeros y letras aleatoriamente

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla llamada `producto` en mi base de datos con los siguientes campos y datos de ejemplo:

```
Producto    |    Materia
==============================
IRE 890          18 g/l Ire
```

Quiero encontrar una sentencia que cambie aleatoriamente una letra, número o símbolo por otro. Por ejemplo:

```
IRE 890 --> AGU 632
18 g/l Ire --> 54 t%f Agu
```

Intenté hacer esta sentencia pero solo me cambia el orden de las letras:

```
update producto set Producto = reverse(Producto)
```

¿Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de hacerlo es usando la función Rand() y la concatenación de cada uno de los resultados, te dejo un ejemplo de como seria:

```
SELECT id, concat(
    char(floor(65+(rand()*25))), 
    char(floor(65+(rand()*25))),
    char(floor(65+(rand()*25)))) AS cadenaString
FROM testing
```

**En tu caso concreto:**

```
update producto set Producto = concat(
        char(floor(65+(rand()*25))), 
        char(floor(65+(rand()*25))),
        char(floor(65+(rand()*25))))
```

**Editado**

Aquí lo tienes aunque con el ejemplo anterior podrías haber llegado a este sin problemas.

```
update producto set Producto = CONCAT(
    char(floor(65+(rand()*25))), 
    char(floor(65+(rand()*25))),
    char(floor(65+(rand()*25))),
    ' ',
    floor(rand()*(10)),
    floor(rand()*(10)),
    floor(rand()*(10))) AS cadenaStrings
```

Comment: Esa funcion funciona, pero me cambia `IRE 890` por `HWO`. Lo que yo busco es que me cambie `IRE 890` por `HWO 426`, que siga el mismo patrón

Comment: Debe de seguir el mismo patrón que tenga el original, sea cual sea ese patrón

Comment: He editado mi respuesta con la solución completa

Comment: La he visto, pero estoy intentando averiguar la funcion para que me siga el mismo patrón de la original pero en todos los datos que tengo, porque por ejemplo, tengo un producto que se llama `NELAND 39`, entonces ya tendría que ser otro patron

Comment: Y si utilizas una función relacionado a un split? digo, así tomaría lo que está antes del espacio y lo que está después...

Answer (score 0):

```
update producto set Producto= concat(


(SELECT (case 
         when(ascii(substring(Producto,1,1))<=47 and ascii(substring(Producto,1,1))>=33) /*Caracteres como %*/
         then (char(floor(33+(rand()*14))))

         when(ascii(substring(Producto,1,1))<=57 and ascii(substring(Producto,1,1))>=48) /*Numeros*/
         then (char(floor(48+(rand()*10))))

         when (ascii(substring(Producto,1,1))<=90 and ascii(substring(Producto,1,1))>=65) /*Letras mayus */
         then (char(floor(65+(rand()*25))))

         when (ascii(substring(Producto,1,1))<=122 and ascii(substring(Producto,1,1))>=97) /*letras minus*/
         then (char(floor(97+(rand()*25))))

         else substring(Producto,1,1) /*Si el caracter no esta como los espacios, los deja igual*/

        end)
),

    (SELECT (case 
         when(ascii(substring(Producto,2,1))<=47 and ascii(substring(Producto,2,1))>=33)
         then (char(floor(33+(rand()*14))))

         when(ascii(substring(Producto,2,1))<=57 and ascii(substring(Producto,2,1))>=48)
         then (char(floor(48+(rand()*10))))

         when (ascii(substring(Producto,2,1))<=90 and ascii(substring(Producto,2,1))>=65)
         then (char(floor(65+(rand()*25))))

         when (ascii(substring(Producto,2,1))<=122 and ascii(substring(Producto,2,1))>=97)
         then (char(floor(97+(rand()*25))))

          else substring(Producto,2,1)

        end)
),

    (SELECT (case 
         when(ascii(substring(Producto,3,1))<=47 and ascii(substring(Producto,3,1))>=33)
         then (char(floor(33+(rand()*14))))

         when(ascii(substring(Producto,3,1))<=57 and ascii(substring(Producto,3,1))>=48)
         then (char(floor(48+(rand()*10))))

         when (ascii(substring(Producto,3,1))<=90 and ascii(substring(Producto,3,1))>=65)
         then (char(floor(65+(rand()*25))))

         when (ascii(substring(Producto,3,1))<=122 and ascii(substring(Producto,3,1))>=97)
         then (char(floor(97+(rand()*25))))

         else substring(Producto,3,1)

        end)
),

    (SELECT (case 
         when(ascii(substring(Producto,4,1))<=47 and ascii(substring(Producto,4,1))>=33)
         then (char(floor(33+(rand()*14))))

         when(ascii(substring(Producto,4,1))<=57 and ascii(substring(Producto,4,1))>=48)
         then (char(floor(48+(rand()*10))))

         when (ascii(substring(Producto,4,1))<=90 and ascii(substring(Producto,4,1))>=65)
         then (char(floor(65+(rand()*25))))

         when (ascii(substring(Producto,4,1))<=122 and ascii(substring(Producto,4,1))>=97)
         then (char(floor(97+(rand()*25))))

         else substring(Producto,4,1)

        end)
)


);
```

Esto de puede Servir, distingue si es mayúsculas, minúsculas y caracteres como %, respetando los espacios.
Solo cambia los primero 4 caracteres pero es para que se tenga una idea.